# A command to tell whether we are inside docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables

As a novice user of a complicated CI system, trying out scripts, I am confused whether my scripts are executed directly by my system's bash, or from a docker container running on the same system. Hence the question: what command (environment variable query or whatever) could tell me whether I am in docker or not?

Comment: It can be impossible to tell if you're in a container, unless you know something unique in your container that isn't in your host environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I guess you are trying to find out whether your script is run from within the context of a docker container OR from within the host machine which runs docker.
- Another way of looking at this is: you have a script which is running and this script is actually a process. And any given process has an associated PID.
- You might want to find out if this process is running within a docker container or directly within the host machine.
- Let's say that your process runs within docker container, then we can conclude that docker process is the parent of your process
- Running the `top` command would list all the processes in the machine. Then using another command `ps -axfo pid,uname,cmd` would give full listing of processes
- Let's say you have identified the parent process id (for eg: 2871). Now you can run

`docker ps | awk '{ print $1}' | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }} {{ .Config.Hostname }}' | grep 2871`

Using this you can identify the container containing the process

- If we run pstree, we could the process tree all the way upto boot process

Courtesy:

[Finding out to which docker container a process belongs to](https://maxcnunes.com/post/2014/10/19/finding-out-to-which-docker-container-a-process-belongs-to/)

[how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153976/how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself in a container, you must have execute a command to enter that container.

If you forgot where you are, type `docker ps`. If it fails, you are in a docker container.

**Edit :**

Obviously, this simple trick does not work when you run docker in docker.

Comment: could the person who votes down question and answer please be a bit more explicit?

Comment: `docker ps` is not a bulletproof way, btw. You can be running docker in your docker.

Comment: since I am pretty sure that I am not running docker in docker, the answer will help me nonetheless - the more so if it be confirmed that for fundamental reasons there can be no bulletproof answer

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well you're right, but that's rare, to use docker in docker. Maybe this simple solution it's ok for Joachim